# PHP URL attribute with JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

I am making an HTML5 game, and there is a new HTML page for every level. The results of every level are stored in a JS variable.

How do I pass that information to the next page using the URL?

I was thinking of something like

> `www.example.com/level5.php?lvl1=10&lvl2=15&lvl3=13`

and so on.

How do I put JS variable values into this type of address?

I don't need to access this information with JS, but I just need to add information.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever tried append?

Comment: Hm, so if I want to cheat, I just pass &lvl1=9999999999999. Instant high score! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "href" attribute value of a link using jQuery:

```
$("#lvl2link").attr("href","www.example.com/level2.php?lvl1=" + score);
```

The same effect can be achieved without jQuery.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPv93/1/

Comment: so how do I use window.location with this method?

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
var lvl1 = "10";
var lvl2 = "15";
window.location.href = "www.example.com/level5.php?lvl1="+lvl1+"&lvl2="+lvl2;
```

Then to create variables in PHP from this URL use GET:

```
$lvl1 = $_GET['lvl1'];
$lvl2 = $_GET['lvl2'];
```

Comment: this should work, but I need to create variables based on what's currently in the address, and how do I do that? Sorry, I'm kinda new to javascript

Comment: Are you looking to put variable values into the url, or get variable values from the url?

Answer (score 0):

You could access the $_GET-Variables in Javascript with the following snippet:

```
(function(){ // Import GET Vars
   document.$_GET = [];
   var urlHalves = String(document.location).split('?');
   if(urlHalves[1]){
      var urlVars = urlHalves[1].split('&');
      for(var i=0; i<=(urlVars.length); i++){
         if(urlVars[i]){
            var urlVarPair = urlVars[i].split('=');
            document.$_GET[urlVarPair[0]] = urlVarPair[1];
         }
      }
   }
})();
```

To access them use:

```
document.$_GET['lvl1']
```

Credit:
http://failchad.blogspot.ch/2009/01/accessing-get-variables-in-javascript.html

To add information use the snippet from `@tommyf`

Answer (score 0):

What about a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) to contain every result? As long as the session is active (that generally means as long as the browser is open), the score is updated at the end of each levels. If there is no score in the session, the first level should be loaded. To save progression, you could give a "progression key" that the user will need to enter the next time.

As an alternative, if you prefer to only use javascript, you could look into [HTML5 LocalStorage](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/04/html5-localstorage-offline-web-applications/). If you take into account that the browser already has HTML5 compatibility, your situation can be a good candidate.

What is wrong with GET parameters is that regardless the name you will choose to store the highscores in the url, people will investigate and soon be able to alterate their highscores to unlock whatever bonuses will come with good scores, or even get to the top of the list to spam (ie: rank #1: buy this blablabla $xx blabla.com (9999999999 points)). LocalStorage is a little harder to cheat (but easy enough), while session variables are much harder to cheat with.